# How can I read .c3d files in PHP?

Tags: php, format, ascii

I have a .c3d file which contains an animation. I want to generate information using the data from that file but when I open it in Nodepad++, it doesn't show the data and instead displays random ASCII characters.

For example:

> Height

I can open this in an external software and see the data but I need to be able to read it using PHP

Comment: See https://www.c3d.org/overview.html

Comment: @adder I have looked at this site and tried all their free software's but I still am unable to read it in a proper format where I can use PHP to retrieve the data

Comment: You could look at the source code of the free programs to see how they do it.